# Amplify with a cordova / phonegap+ meteor stack?

Tags: cordova, meteor, amplifyjs

Is amplify.js compatible with a cordova (ios and android) + meteor solution?

Need to be sure that I can persist data locally to survive a power failure on the device.

Answer (score 0):

So AmplifyJS has 3 big features; and meteor handles a lot of these features already. If you are looking for the data persistance feature of localstorage with AmplifyJS I would suggest you look at a more specific library like https://github.com/bevacqua/local-storage - it would be similar syntax but without the overhead of the AmplifyJS lib and you could be more explicit where you tie into the app.